# How to find the long term proportion of time a markov chain will spend on a state?

Tags: markov-process

I have this question:

$n$ processors are arranged in an ordered list. At every step, a task comes into the first processor in the list, if it cannot solve the task, it goes on to the second processor, if the second one cannot solve it, it moves on to the third and so on until it either gets solved or it leaves the last processor unsolved. If processor $i$ solved the problem, then it switches places with the processor preceding it. If processor $1$ solved the problem, or none of the processors solved it, the list stays the same. Pocessor $i$, if attempting a task, will solve it, independently of everything else, with probability $p_i$. If a Markov chain with states $(\sigma (1),...,\sigma(n))$ is created from this process, where $\sigma$ is a permutation, what are its long term probabilities? I.e. what is $$\lim P(X_n=(\sigma(1),...,\sigma(n))$$
Since a given permutation can only transition into a transposition of itself
$$P((x_1,...,x_i,x_{i+1},...,x_n)\to(x_1,...,x_{i+1},x_{i},...,x_n))=p_{x_i}\prod_{k=1}^i (1-p_{x_k})$$
However, the long term proportions have me stumped. I solved the specific case for $n=2,3$ to look for some pattern in the expressions but I came up empty handed, maybe because of some mistake in the computations. 

Any suggestions or hints?

Comment: Could you please explain how a sequential set of transitions through an ordered list corresponds to a Markov chain on the set of permutations of the list elements?

Comment: @whuber Number the $n$ processors $1,...,n$, we say the Markov Chain is in state $X_i=(\sigma(1),...,\sigma(n))$ if at transition $i$, the first processor in the ordered list is $\sigma(1)$, the second $\sigma(2)$ and so on. For example, say $\sigma = (12)$, then the Markov Chain at step $i$ is $(2,1,3,4,...,n)$

Comment: I still cannot see any connection between this and your description of processors passing a task along, one to another, in a given order.  Where have you presented any mechanism that would change the order of the processors?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I forgot to add that. It is now in the question. "If processor $i$ solved the problem, then it switches places with the processor preceding it. If processor $1$ solved the problem, or none of the processors solved it, the list stays the same. "